# Задать Where на колличество полных лет позьвателей между 18 и 22 mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

У меня есть таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `id`        INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name`  VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `gender`    INT(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '0 - не указан, 1 - мужчина, 2 - женщина.',
    `birth_date`    INT(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Дата в unixtime.',
    `phone` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

По завпросу: `SELECT name, floor(datediff(YEAR, curdate(), birth_date)) FROM`users`;` выдает имена и возрост людей.

Делаю условие:

```
SELECT name where  floor( datediff(curdate(), FROM_UNIXTIME(birth_date))/365 ) > 18 and  floor( datediff(curdate(), FROM_UNIXTIME(birth_date))/365 ) < 22 FROM `users`
```

Получаю ошибку:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where  floor( datediff(curdate(), FROM_UNIXTIME(birth_date))/365 ) > 18 and  flo' at line 1

Где я допусти ошибку?

Comment: А что, действительно есть такие SQL, что позволяют WHERE перед FROM?

Comment: @СмоляноеЧучелко ну селект же позволил... XD

Comment: SELECT без WHERE подобен SELECTу с WHERE. Только без WHERE.

Comment: *ну селект же позволил* угу, позволил... правда, выдал при этом ошибку 1064, но кому это интересно...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Язык SQL строго описывает, где должно быть выражение where в запросе и произвольно менять его местоположение нельзя.

Поэтому слегка подправленный синтаксически корректный запрос будет выглядеть так:

```
SELECT name 
FROM `users`
where  
    floor( datediff(curdate(), FROM_UNIXTIME(birth_date))/365 ) > 18 and
    floor( datediff(curdate(), FROM_UNIXTIME(birth_date))/365 ) < 22
```

Но что про него необходимо учесть (помимо некорректной обработки высокосных лет) - этот запрос не может использовать индексы. У вас правда и нет индекса на birth_date

Эффективнее и, на самом деле проще - посчитать подходящие даты рождения и искать по ним. Ведь у людей возрастом 18-22 года день рождения и был в диапазоне между 22 и 18 годами ранее:

```
select name
from users
where birth_date between UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now() - interval 22 year)
    and UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now() - interval 18 year)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name 
FROM `users`
where  
    floor( datediff(curdate(), FROM_UNIXTIME(birth_date))/365 ) > 18 and
    floor( datediff(curdate(), FROM_UNIXTIME(birth_date))/365 ) < 22
```